# Correct implementation of polymorphism without Java smell

Tags: java, polymorphism

I built 2 classes that implement the same interface and do different logic based on instance type. Some of the methods receives the interface type as a parameter and do different logic based on the instance type. This would be easy to do using instanceof, but I need to do this without any smell.

Here is the code I tried:

```
public class Concrete1 implements Interf{
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete1 s) {return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean isMatch(Interf s) {return false;}
}
public class Concrete2 implements Interf{
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete2 s) {return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean isMatch(Interf s) {return false;}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Concrete1 c1=new Concrete1();
    Concrete2 c1=new Concrete2();
    Interf i1=new Concrete1();
    Interf i2=new Concrete2();
    System.out.println(c1.isMatch(c1));
    System.out.println(c1.isMatch(c2));
    System.out.println(i1.isMatch(i1));
    System.out.println(i1.isMatch(i2));
}
```

Expected output would be:

```
true
false
true
false
```

Instead, I get:

```
true
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i found that works, is using a visitor pattern.
Essentially, when a variable is declared to be of type 'Interf' and then a method takes it as a parameter, the compiler links the call to a method that takes a parameter of type 'Interf'. Meaning that any functionality in the methods that take 'Concrete1' or 'Concrete2' is never even looked at.
To overcome this we need to make the declared type to be concrete.

The visitor patter goes as follows:

```
public interface Interf {
    public boolean isMatch(Interf in);
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete1 con1);
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete2 con2);
}
public class Concrete1 implements Interf{
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete1 con1){return true;}
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete2 con2){return false;}
    public boolean isMatch(Interf in){return in.isMatch(this);}
}
public class Concrete2 implements Interf{
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete2 con1){return true;}
    public boolean isMatch(Concrete1 con2){return false;}
    public boolean isMatch(Interf in){return in.isMatch(this);}
}
```

The key point is the line: `public boolean isMatch(Interf in){return in.isMatch(this);`
This means that if the argument the method takes is not concrete you re-envoke the call in the parameter using the current active class as the declared type. This way the classes essentialy identify themselves to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The only line different to your expectation is the third line, the result of:

```
i1.isMatch(i1)
```

`i1` is a reference to an `Interf`, so the compiler chooses the method which takes an `Interf`. It can't select a method which takes a `Concrete1` because it only considers methods which exist on the type `Interf`.

Comment: is there any way around this without casting?

Comment: @MegaFlipFlop any way around what?

Comment: You expect that this method will be called `isMatch(Concrete1 c)` but polymorphism works by override and your "override" method is only this one ```isMatch(Interf i)```

Comment: how can i implement my interface and still get my functionality the way i want it. in general both implementations are kept in a list of type Interf so i cant have the referance type be exact.

Comment: As I said you expect that this method could be called by polymorphism `public boolean isMatch(Concrete1 s) {return true;}` but It can't because this method is implementation-specific. Here the `match()` method is about "overload" and overload is a compile-time resolution not runtime one like polymorphism...

Comment: then what method can i use to return true when both types match and false otherwise assuming that instanceoff, getClass() and casting are not an option?

Comment: @MegaFlipFlop without those options, you can't.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. i found a way around this using a visitor pattern.